# Declaring php class member variables

Tags: php

I was trying to write a class in such simple way

```
class piklu
{
   private $x=5;
   public function display()
   {
      echo $this->$x;
   }
}
```

but when after creating object of this class I'm calling the function display it is displaying an error unkown variable $x. Can any body suggest me what exactly I have to do to declare a private member variable in php.

Answer (score 8):

Your echo statement is incorrect, which is your problem. It should be:

```
public function display()
{
    echo $this->x;
}
```

Note that there's only one `$` here: right before the keyword `this`. You mistakenly had two dollar signs.

Comment: THAT MEANS I DONT NEED TO USE '$' SYMBOL WHEN I'M PINTING A CLASS VARIABLE????????????????

Comment: No, you do need the `$` symbol. It appears before the keyword `this`, which is how you access your class variable.

Comment: YAAAAA IT WORKS....THANKZZZZZ MAN....I'M POSTING ANOTHER QUESTION PLEASE CHECK THAT ALSO.....

Answer (score 6):

You have done a silght mistake on calling variable. You can call the class member variable by

```
$this->x
```

Comment: THAT MEANS I DONT NEED TO USE '$' SYMBOL WHEN I'M PINTING A CLASS VARIABLE????????????????

Comment: $this means the current php object. To call the object's variable the syntax is $this->variable name. In this case $this->x